# Is there an isListening() method or... How to implement isListening()

Tags: android, speech-recognition

The [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class includes methods such as isRecognitionAvailable(), startListening() and stopListening(), but doesn't have a method to check whether it is *currently* listening.

I checked the [RecognitionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html) class too and it doesn't have such an "isListening()" method as well.

Any idea **why?** (e.g. it's useless/meaningless, too easy to implement by app programmer, etc.)

If indeed there is no SDK API to provide this function, what is the best way to implement such an "isListening()" method?

Is it as simple as setting a boolean in onReadyForSpeech() and clearing it in onEndOfSpeech()?

Or do I need something more sophisticated, such as a counter... or even an [Atomic](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) counter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define "listening". Does it start from the point you:

- Called startListening() ?
- Received onReadyForSpeech() ?

I believe the distinction between these two (valid and useful) scenarios is the reason for leaving the implementation to the API user.

Then, as @HoanNguyen said, declare a boolean data member in RecognitionListener:

- Set it *right after* you call startListening(), or as soon as you enter onReadyForSpeech(). It's your call...
- Reset it in onResults(), onError() **and** *right after* you call SpeechRecognizer.cancel().

Note: As @HoanNguyen correctly noted, resetting that boolean right after you called stopListening() is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you know when you've called `startListening()`, and you know when you've called `stopListening()`. why do you need a listener?

just set a flag to tell yourself what state you are in (listening, or not).

Comment: Because the listener could stop listening for many reasons, way before stopListening() is called (and even if it is *not* called). onError and possibly a few other scenario.

Comment: it is listening until you get onResults or onError.

Comment: @HoanNguyen or I explicity call stopListening(). Are there really only 3 cases that stop the listener? i.e. *that* simple? Thanks.

Comment: When you call stopListening does not mean the process finish. If you call startListening after stopListening you will likely got server busy error. Only cancel() and the two cases I commented above means you can call startListining again

Comment: @HoanNguyen Ah! See? It's not caveat-free as it looks on the surface. :) I had to get this clarification from someone (you, thank you) and even then, the solution is distributed over 3 different methods and a class plus an interface... It would have been nice if Android provided this right from the start.

Comment: @srf okay ... so can you set `listening = fale` in the error handler? i don't see the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing that calling startListening() sometimes does nothing ---meaning onReadyForSpeech() is never called. This happens a few times after calling startListening(). and its random when it fails. In this case an isListening() method would be useful.